# Phase control circuit

Tags: current, potentiometer

I am designing a phase control circuit to control a Single phase AC induction motor. In the circuit 50K potentiometer is used in series with 10K resistor to control the the phase angle of the signal. But my need is to use 10K potentiometer. So I decided to use 10K pot with 50K resistor. But I have a doubt that interchanging a value of pot and resistor might affect the performance of the circuit.Please clarify this doubt. Any other suggestion are welcome. Thank you. Sorry for crappy images.[image]

Comment: The circuits are not the same and will not give the same range of adjustment. The circuit with the 10k pot will have a smaller adjustment range than the circuit with the 50k pot. Not much more can be said about it without a good deal more information.

Comment: There is a schematic editor which you can use to draw the above diagrams with greater clarity. Adding more details about the phase control circuit would help your question a lot.

Comment: Generally, induction motor speed is governed by the AC frequency. Do you actually understand what you are proposing may not make sense?

Comment: These fixed and variable resistors *by themselves* are not going to affect the phase angle at all.

Comment: @uint128_t Hopefully, there IS a phase control circuit and Dhans doesn't think that his drawing is the circuit.

Answer (score 1):

What you have drawn is not a potentiometer circuit. It is a variable resistor and a fixed resistor. A potentiometer has a third connection that is movable from one end of the resistor to the other.

You have not shown anything about the circuit that is connected to the circuit shown. With either a potentiometer or a fixed resistor, what happens when the resistor or potentiometer is adjusted is partly determined by the remainder of the circuit. If the remainder of the circuit is known, it is possible to calculate the effect of changing the values of the components shown. With the information given, all that can be said is that changing the potentiometer or variable resistor value will result in performance other than what was originally intended regardless of what value is used for the fixed resistor.